# Visual Studio 2010: "Platform" dropdown in "Configuration Manager" isn't showing up

Tags: visual-studio-2010, wcf, windows-services, installation, setup-project

I'm trying to add Setup Project for my solution to install Windows Service.
I right click the solution in VS 2010 -> Add -> New Project -> Other Project Types -> Setup and Deployment -> Visual Studio Installer -> Setup Project.
[image]

Then I right click "Setup1" project -> Add -> Project Output:
I choose the Windows Service project("MagicEightBallServiceHost" on screenshot)
Since I want installer to be build for both Debug and Release I choose "(Active)"(may be I'm wrong on this one).

[image]

If I build the solution now, the Setup1 won't build and I'll get this in Output:

> ------ Skipped Rebuild All: Project: Setup1, Configuration: Release ------ 
>   Project not selected to build for this solution configuration

So, I go to "Build Menu" -> "Configuration Manager" -> I can't change platform for Setup1 project, because it has no dropdown. Why can't I choose the platform for it?
[image]

I've tried it on several projects, please help. 
How can I make Setup Project to build "MagicEightBallServiceHost" project in x64 for any configuration(Debug/Release) ?
Thanks.

Comment: Ok, I think I'll try to follow instructions regarding setup project in this link:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt39148a%28VS.80%29.aspx

Comment: I've just encountered this problem too. Would be interested to hear if /how you solved it.

Comment: Richard, I've reproduced this issue again for you.
And the solution is simple but not obvious at all: just click on Setup project in Solution Explorer and then change "TargetPlatform" in Properties window:
https://copy.com/MuuAZH1d4uFmiphH

Comment: Cheers Joe, saved my sanity, that was driving me mad. Thanks a lot - appreciate it.